Differentiate the scripts that obtain an access token using the Client Credentials Grant type
In Microsoft EntraID I have a Application registration that has two client secrets.

I want to obtain a access token from this App Registration using the client credentials grant type using two separate python scripts (script1 and script2)
The problem is that there is no way to differentiate if the JWT token was obtained from script1 or script2.
For each script I used a different client secret.
To get the the JWT access token I used this curl and I specified that I want to use client credentials grant type and I tried using it with different client_secrets. But the JWT was the same and there is no way to differentiate them.
curl --location 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/5fdbbf9b-ae6b-4986-8349-46baf9cffc1a/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: fpc=AsBGgX8tBlFBpcISkM-uVZHIlH0WAQAAANI0F94OAAAA' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=4c670161-3e27-441f-b694-6538e755d94e' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=api://4c670161-3e27-441f-b694-6538e755d94e/.default'

Question 1: Is there a way to differentiate clients that use client credentials grant type when they use different secrets?
Question 2: Am I wrongly using this grant type? This is the grant type recommended for a machine to machine situation.

I do not think you can differentiate the client which use different secret.

I agree with @wenbo, you cannot differentiate between clients that use client credentials grant type based on secrets.

Client credentials grant type itself does not differentiate tokens based on client secrets.
The client credentials grant type is used to acquire an access token that represents the application itself, rather than a specific user or client.
The access token obtained using the client credentials grant type is identical that uses the same application ID and secret.

Generated access token:
curl --location 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: fpc=xxx' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=ClientID' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=api://xxx/.default'


Hence you can differentiate the access token only based on iss, appid, roles, aud, tid claims.


You can make use of client credentials grant type for scenarios involving machine-to-machine authentication, where the application accesses its own resources.

